# Why doesn't datetime.time have astimezone?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I'm converting a `datetime.time` object's timezone to a different timezone. It looks like the easiest way is to create a `datetime.datetime` from the `datetime.time` object, then do the conversion.

Like this:

```
dt = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), self.data)
utc_dt = dt.astimezone(utc)
self.data = utc_dt.time()
```

Why doesn't datetime.time have astimezone like datetime.datetime does? It seems like that would make things much easier. Is it because timezone offset can be ambiguous without the date?

Comment: Because a timezone is date-sensitive. So "yes".

Comment: yes. some timezones use DST, which requires the date along with it to calculate the exact offset.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Timezones require a date, the time alone is not enough.

That's because:

1. You need to be able to determine if DST applies.
2. You need to know what offsets to apply. Timezones are not static, they have changed over time, adjusting DST start and end dates, as well as the offset from UTC.